# How can i call an outerClass constructor inside an innerClass constructor

Tags: java, constructor

```
public class Adresse{
    private String rue,ville;
    private int codepostale,numero;

    Adresse(String rue,String ville,int num,int code){
        
        this.rue=rue;
        this.ville=ville;
        codepostale=code;
        numero=num;
        
    }
   class Citizen{
    private String nom,prenom;
        private Adresse adr;
        
        
        Citizen(String nom,String prenom,String ville,String rue,int num,int code)
        {
          this.nom=nom;
          this.prenom=prenom;
          this.adr=new Adresse(rue, ville, num, code);
         
        }
}


}
```

this code generates an error when i try to construct a citizen
"No enclosing instance of type Adresse is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Adresse (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Adresse)."

how can i fix this? thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you want to make Citizen an inner nested class of Adresse? Nested classes in java are special cases. Normally every class should be defined in it's own file separately.

Comment: yes i know i prefer it too,but the assignement demands it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make your class static and call with the "outer.inner" class notation.

ie:

```
    public class Adresse {
    private String rue,ville;
    private int codepostale,numero;

    Adresse(String rue,String ville,int num,int code){

        this.rue=rue;
        this.ville=ville;
        codepostale=code;
        numero=num;

    }
    static class citizen{
        private String nom,prenom;
        private Adresse adr;


    citizen(String nom,String prenom,String ville,String rue,int num,int code){
        this.nom=nom;
        this.prenom=prenom;
        this.adr=new Adresse(rue, ville, num, code);

        }
    }

}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Adresse.citizen a = new Adresse.citizen("a", "a", "a", "a", 1, 1);
    }
}
```